# Jasmine spec has no expectation

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following code:
(beforeEach)

```
spyOn(HttpService, 'post').and.callFake(function (url, paging, targetSpinner) {
        return $q.when(_fakeServerResponse);
    });
```

The test case:

```
it('should compare size', function () {
    service.get({},'','').then(function (serviceResponse) {
        expect(serviceResponse.x).toEqual(_fakeServerResponse.x);
```

and the get method:

```
return httpService.post(apiUrls).then(postComplete)
```

My problem is, as mentioned in the title: some why jasmine says that there are not expectations.

The service itself when not running a test is used:

```
myService.get(data, param1, param2).then(getComplete);
```

I will also add that when running the spec case, getComplete is never called, which is the source of the problem as I see it (yet I don't know why it doesn't get called).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q is asynchronous. The returned promise will only be resolved at the next scope digest. Your test should rather look like:

```
it('should compare size', inject(function($rootScope) {
  var actualX;
  service.get({},'','').then(function(serviceResponse) {
    actualX = serviceResponse.x;
  };

  $rootScope.$apply(); // that will actually resolve the promise

  expect(actualX).toEqual(_fakeServerResponse.x);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it and I got the response back, BUT, after the postComplete method returns I get the error:Error: Unexpected request: POST /api/v1/User/Index
No more request expected which means the then clause in the test never enters. How can this be? All requests should be replaced by fake one shouldn't it?

Comment: It's hard explaining the reason without seeing your code.